# updateSelectInput no funciona correctamente en shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy intentando hacer un updateselectinput pero no funciona correctamente. Cuando cambio el input de `datalab_data`, las opciones en el selectinput `datalab_columns` no cambian y se mantienen con los nombres de columnas de Events. Espero q podais ayudarme con esta parte del codigo:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "dashboard_shiny", titleWidth = 250
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 250,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Lab", tabName = "datalab", icon = icon("flask"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("datalab",
            fluidRow(
              column(6, wellPanel(radioButtons("datalab_data", "Select data source:", choices = c("Events", "Worknotes", "Occupations")))),
              column(6, wellPanel(selectInput("datalab_columns", "Select data columns:", choices = "All Columns", multiple = T)))
            )
           )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$datalab_data != "", {
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Events"){
      columns <- events() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Worknotes"){
      columns <- worknotes() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Occupations"){
      columns <- occupations() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "datalab_columns", choices = c("All Columns", columns), selected = "All Columns")
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi there, this is [es.so]. Please translate your question to Spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so], tu pregunta debes traducirla al Castellano de lo contrario terminará cerrada. De paso, te invito a realizar el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: El observerevent nunca detecta un cambio, ya que el input datalab_data siempre es distinto de "". Quita el la prueba lógica ! =